# How to display one category per page for a particular category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am fairly new to WordPress. I am developing a website with a custom theme (I am trying to learn by write one). The website is about automobiles and has categories as bikes, cars, copters etc. I have to display one of the categories (bikes) on the navigation menu.
Now when I click on the this menu, it should take me to a separate page which display only the posts about the `bikes` category. And in this page, I want to display one post per page. So I made a `category-8.php` (`8` being the id of bikes category).
So I put the following code in there:

```
<?php query_posts( array(  'cat' => 8, 'posts_per_page' => 1  ) ) ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
      <h3><?php wp_title(); ?></h3>
      <h6>BY <?php the_author(); ?> |<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h6>
      <p> <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
   <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<p style="float:left;"><?php next_post_link('%link &laquo; Newer Entries',true) ?></p>
<p style="float:right;"><?php previous_post_link('Older Entries &raquo %link;',true) ?></p> 

<?php endif; // end of the loop. ?>
```

So the problem here is:

1. The post title says `Bikes`, even though my posts is titled `Hot wheels`.
   However, it shows the post content correctly.
2. `previous_post_link()` gives link to another page. I would expect that to give the link to the same page but an older category.
   Please not the link to this category page is `localhost/myBlog?cat=8`

And the previous_post_link points to `localhost/myBlog?page=114`

Why is it so? Am I doing something wrong here?

More importantly, do I need to custom define the `page.php` or `single.php` rather than working on `category-8.php`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[wp_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) is meant for the `<title>` tag in your `header.php` file. What you want here is [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title).

[next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [previous_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) are used on single posts only, not category pages.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had mistakenly written that.  Now, can you please also  help me with the other problem (pagination one) which is the bigger concern?

Comment: Ohh.. did'nt know that. Thanks. So what should I do, if I want to display posts of "bike" category, one post per page?

Comment: You probably need `get_query_var('paged')` to get your current page number and then pass something like `&paged=$pages_number` in your `query_post`. Read the pagination part on [`query_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: Okay, passed that too. Now my code looks like:  <?php query_posts( array('paged' => $paged,  'cat' => 8, 'posts_per_page' => 1  ) ) ?>   And removed the next_post_link and previous_post_link part. I executed the above code and now no link to previous or next link appears, as I expected.   So now, ho do I get the link for the next (or previous category)?  Thanks for stopping by and replying.

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't use `query_post. It would be better to use `WP_Query` and [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) for that task.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22629/discussion-between-user1314305-and-rrikesh)